# Subset rows in one data frame based on values from another data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, subset

I have two data frames: `df1` and `df2`. They both have four columns; three with the same names `ID`, `Year` and `Week` and one that are different from each other.

```
>df1
ID      Year      Oxygen     Week
----    ------    -------    -------
1       2004      18          1
1       2005      17          1 
2       2006      17          1
2       2007      18          1 
3       2008      19          1
3       2010      20          1
3       2010      20          1
4       2012      16          1
5       2013      18          1
6       2014      18          1

>df2
ID      Year      Kg       Week
----    ------   -----    -------
1       2004      20        1
1       2005      35        2
2       2006      30        2
3       2007      15        1
3       2008      70        2
4       2009      40        1
5       2013      55        1
6       2012      40        1
6       2014      10        2
7       2013      15        1
```

I would like to produce a new data frame which contains the rows from `df1` only when the combination of `ID` and `Year` in `df1` also are present in `df2`. The `Week` might be the same or not for that row, but I don't want to take the column `Week` into account. So the first row in `df1` has 1 for `ID` and 2004 for `Year` which also occurs in `df2`. The combination of `ID` and `Year` for the second row in `df1` does also occur in `df2`but have different value for `Week`.

I know how to do it if it only depends on one column:
`df3 <- subset(df1, ID %in% df2$ID)`

There was a solution for this when I didn't have the column `Week` which was:
`df3 <- df1 %>% inner_join(df2)`

But I don't know how to make it depend on both the `ID` and `Year` at the same time without it also takes `Week` into account.

I should end up with the following data frame, which only contain the columns from `df1`:

```
>df3
ID      Year      Oxygen      Week
----    ------    -------    -------
1       2004      18          1
1       2005      17          1
2       2006      17          1
3       2008      19          1
4       2012      16          1
5       2013      18          1
6       2014      18          1
```

Comment: You're describing a semi-join, joining by 2 columns

Comment: Thank you very much @camille. It is exactly what I need. I don't why haven't noticed that specific join function.

Answer (score 0):

`tidyverse` approach

```
library(dplyr)

df3 <-
  df1 %>% 
  inner_join(df2)
```

Comment: I have just added another column which replicates my data in a better way. I had just simplified my data when writing this question and can now see it makes the solution with inner_join not possible.

Comment: And with this approach I end up with a data frame that merges the two data frames. I need to create a new data frame where it only consists of the data in df1.